# Using a List Adapter

Tags: android, listview, textview, xamarin, listadapter

In Xamarin I have a ListView and a ListAdapter and am populating this List with some Tuples.

Here is my code:

```
items = new List<Tuple<string, string>>();

ListView lst = new ListView (this.ApplicationContext);

ListAdapter = new List_Adapter(this, items);
lst.Adapter = ListAdapter;
```

This works correctly.

I am now after each item in the ListView to be a TextView with the following layout:

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:id="@+id/rowTextView" 
 android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:autoLink="all"
 android:padding="10dp"
 android:textSize="16sp" >
</TextView>
```

I have tried this code:

```
ListAdapter = ArrayAdapter<String>(this.ApplicationContext, Resource.Layout.rowTextView, items);
```

However, I get this error:

> 'Android.Widget.ArrayAdapter' is a 'type' but it is used as a
>   'varaible'

Can I have some help to get this working please?

Thanks in advance

**EDIT**

I have modified the code as follows:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this.ApplicationContext, Resource.Layout.rowTextView, items);
```

I am now getting these errors:

> Error CS1502: The best overloaded method match for 'Android.Widget.ArrayAdapter.ArrayAdapter(Android.Content.Context, int, int)' has some invalid arguments
>
> Error CS1503: Argument 3: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.List>' to 'int'

Comment: Shouldn't it be Resource.Id.rowTextView instead of Resource.Layout?